# Sqlite returning 0 rows from table when there are

Tags: sqlite, select

I have a strange situation for the following table.

CREATE TABLE "CommonConfigs" (
`ConfigID`  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`ConfigName`    TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(length ( ConfigName ) < 32),
`ConfigData`    BLOB NOT NULL CHECK(length ( ConfigData ) <= 364),
`ConfigDataSize`    INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY(ConfigID)
)

I have added few rows into this using queries during our application. After that we are trying to fetch everything from this using the query "SELECT * FROM CommonConfigs", but its returning 0.

Later we tried to check manually by opening the database file using sqlitebrowser, and we can see all the rows we inserted. Then I tried to execute same query in sqlitebrowser, and it also return 0 rows.

After checking what query sqlite browser used to display rows, then I ran that manually and its return data properly then.

Seems like select query is working only if I add some condition like Order By, ASC Limit etc., to it like this.

"SELECT * FROM CommonConfigs ORDER BY `_rowid_`"

I have no expertise in understanding this behaviour, so anyone here please tell me why its working like this. This is not always, and it happened only once in our application randomly, just trying to root cause and undersand it.

Thanks

Comment: If that select really returns no records, then nothing is there.  In this case, if you expected some records to be there, you should verify that no part of your application (or outside your application) is deleting records.

Comment: There's no need to make your primary key unique; the former implies the latter, and the latter will add a redundant index. And you don't need not null for an integer primary key.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Only basic "select * from table" is not returning records, but if I use "select * from table order by" return rows like i explained. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for your suggestions, will update it accordingly. Any idea about that select query behaviour I explained ?

Comment: Not possible.  `ORDER BY` has no effect on the size/contents of the result set, only on the order in which the records are returned.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understand, but in my case if I used that working which is strange. Even the sqliteebrowser application behaves same. Any corruption in db or something ?

Comment: I have similar issue, but it's with my unit test. I have seen some data on startup, but not returning data for particular entity. Those entities are hierarchical entities.